# Swift segue not doing what it is supposed to do

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I am having a little problem with a segue in my application. 
When I try to push a segue so that it has a navbar it shows up correctly in the storyboard but not when I try it on my iPhone.

This is an overview of a couple of view controllers where my problem lays.

[image]

This is supposed to be the segue, so you can see that it has a navigation bar and is correctly positioned on the storyboard.

[image]

[image]

This is the view on the iPhone. No navigation bar or nothing. I tried everything but can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

[image]

Does anyone what the problem could be?

A little extra side information: 
I don't know if may have something to do with the problem but the navigation view controller is not always present only when the user is logged in the app. this is decided on a log in screen if the user is not logged in the user will see a normal login screen. Else it will go to navigation view controller with a view did appear function and self.present.

Here is the code that handles that action.

```
 // Sees if the user is logged, If yes --> go to the account detail page else go to the account view.
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "User") {
            do {
                // Create JSON Decoder
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // Decode Note
                _ = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
                guard let loginVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
                        "AccountDetailViewController") as? AccountDetailViewController else { return }
                loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                self.present(loginVC, animated: false, completion: {})
            } catch {
                print("Unable to Decode Note (\(error))")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your login success code. Wanna see how you are pushing your controller.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I've added the code.

Answer (score 2):

You should `push` view controller instead of `present`. Please check this article to know more about [Pushing, Popping, Presenting, & Dismissing ViewControllers](https://medium.com/@felicity.johnson.mail/pushing-popping-dismissing-viewcontrollers-a30e98731df5)

---

You can push `AccountDetailViewController` without segues. And you don't need to call `performSegue(withIdentifier:)` into `tableView`'s `didSelect` function.

- Remove segue from `Interface Builder`

```swift
let navigator = UINavigationController()

guard let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
                        "AccountDetailViewController") as? AccountDetailViewController else { return }
loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

navigator.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will try this solution!

Answer (score 1):

After succesful login, you are presenting `AccountDetailViewController` without adding it in a navigation controller. I would suggest you to use these extensions that i created.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func pushVC(vcName : String) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }


    func pushVC(storyboardName : String, vcName : String)  {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func popVC() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    func makeRootVC(storyBoardName : String, vcName : String) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
         let vc = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
         let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
         nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
         appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav // If using XCode 11 and above, copy var window : UIWindow? in your appDelegate file
         let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionCrossDissolve
         let duration: TimeInterval = 0.6
         UIView.transition(with: appDelegate.window!, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

Now in your case, when a user logs in, you should change your root view controller to `AccountDetailViewController`. So first, copy paste the above extension anywhere in your file and then use it like this:

```
 // Sees if the user is logged, If yes --> go to the account detail page else go to the account view.
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "User") {
            do {
                // Create JSON Decoder
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // Decode Note
                _ = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
                self.makeRootVC(storyBoardName : "Main", vcName :"AccountDetailViewController")
            } catch {
                print("Unable to Decode Note (\(error))")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you add `AccountDetailViewController` as a root then there will no `back` buttons. This is what OP doesn't want to do.

Comment: @emrcftci the OP has made some logical issues. I have suggested him the suitable way.  Or maybe i am mistaken... Let the OP clarify.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response! my root view controller does indeed need to be another one. So I think this won't work.